# Quickly apply a known sort order (old index -> new index mapping) to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

I am trying to performance tune a routine that needs to sort 8 large arrays "in tandem", where one of the arrays is the array to sort by.

- I've already taken care of sorting the first array using a method of my choosing (I'm using TimSort)
- I've already taken care of making sure my array of sorted objects have a property denoting their original index. (e.g. `sortedArray[0].OriginalIndex` would return `2983` if previously `unsortedArry[2983]` turned out to be the first item)

This means if I were to loop over my now sorted array of objects, I think I can just get all other arrays sorted in the same order in the following naïve way:

```cs
private List<object[]> SortInTandem(IndexedObj[] sortedArray, List<object[]> arraysToSort)
    for(int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
       int originalIndex = sortedArray[i].OriginalIndex;
       // Swap the corresponding index from all other arrays to their new position
       foreach(object[] array in arraysToSort) {
          object temp = array[i];
          array[i] = array[originalIndex];
          array[originalIndex] = temp;
       }
    }
    return arraysToSort; // Returning original arrays sorted in-place
}
```

I believe the above algorithm to have the desired result, but it feels less efficient than it could be. (3 times as many assignments as needed?)

I also considered the following approach which minimizes assignments, but requires allocating new arrays to store sorted items, and garbage collecting the old arrays (unless I come up with a way to recycle the allocations between calls):

```cs
private List<object[]> SortInTandem(IndexedObj[] sortedArray, List<object[]> arraysToSort) =>
    arraysToSort.Select(array =>
    {
       object[] tandemArray = new object[array.length];   
       for(int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++)
          tandemArray[i] = array[sortedArray[i].OriginalIndex];
    }); // Returning newly-allocated arrays
```

This sort of thing is done continuously in a performance-critical area of code, so I'm looking for thoughts on how I might get the best of both worlds.

Comment: If you use LINQ you can use the .OrderBy() and .ThenOrderBy().

Comment: @PaulSinnema I've already taken of sorting the array. Now I'm trying to efficiently apply the same sort order to other arrays.

Comment: Have you done performance profiling of your application to identify this piece of code as a bottleneck? Your naïve approach has time complexity `O(n)` which you cannot really improve here, so you're looking at micro-optimizations right now. Is that worth the effort?

Comment: That being said, if parallelizing is an option, that would help

Comment: @Xerillio yes, this was identified as a bottleneck after profiling with both VS and Resharper. The parent routine heavily exercises all CPUs and heap allocation, and garbage collection cycles are becoming noticeably long, so we're doing everything we can to hammer it down. This particular routine is being run concurrently on 64 cores to chip away at a queue of several thousand standalone datasets. The above sorting process is a big part of the routine happening for a single dataset (as part of a single task running on one core - so all other cores are already in use).

Comment: @Alain Ah, right, misread that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking more about the second solution above (allocating new arrays) - it occurred to me that the list of arrays passed in can also be "repurposed" once their sorted variant has been produced, so I actually only need to allocate one new array and then I can reuse the ones passed in to prepare additional results:

```cs
// Note the allocated arraysToSort passed in will be repurposed to produced a new set of sorted
// arrays, so the caller must be sure to discard their references and only use what is returned.
private List<object[]> SortInTandem(IndexedObj[] sortedArray, List<object[]> arraysToSort)
{
    List<object[]> sortedArrays = new List<object[]>(arraysToSort.Count);
    object[] tandemArray = new object[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < arraysToSort.Count; i++)
    {  
       for(int j = 0; j < sortedArray.length; j++)
          tandemArray[j] = array[sortedArray[j].OriginalIndex];
       sortedArrays.Add(tandemArray);
       tandemArray = arraysToSort[i];
    }
    return sortedArrays; // Returning one newly-allocated + all but one original arrays repurposed
}
```

Comment: You're using `object[]` arrays all over the place. If the original data is of a more concrete type, there's likely a lot of boxing and unboxing occurring. If that's the case, consider making this a generic function to avoid that penalty.

Comment: Original arrays are definitely not of structs, but yes in my own code I will likely be using generics ( SortInTandem<T>) - I wanted to keep the example generic because in theory the other arrays to sort might all be arrays of different types of objects. Comment is much appreciated though!